# Need to Reduce time consumed by consumer to display messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**I am able to get the messages from the Kafka topics but it takes too much of time to read the messages. Is there any way to reduce the time consumption. And also I need to know whether we can get only last message from Kafka topic..... Please help me.**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class SimpleConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Kafka consumer configuration settings
    String topicName = "you";
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.174.132:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "60000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

    // Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            // print the offset,key and value for the consumer records.
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i think long time is taking to read first message right ?? is subsequent messages fast ? or every message consumption is taking time ?

Comment: every message is taking long time

Comment: Try to reduce poll time from 100 to 1. and observe

Comment: Can you define "long" and what your target latency is? And yes, you can read any message from Kafka by using `seek()` to position the consumer to whatever offset you want.

Comment: Can u show some code about seek() @ Matthias J. Sax